# IF Else string check condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a records like below :

```
Name                Count
123456M2.txt        NULL
123456M2.txt        15
123456M.txt         NULL
```

- First record shoud show me NULL, as there is a number after "M" letter in name and Count < 0
- Second record shoud show me 1, and there is a number after "M" letter in name and Count > 0
- Third record should show me "some number from another field" as, there is no number after "M" letter in name.

Can you guide me on how to write this query.

I am able to do CASE - WHEN query, but not able to proceed with IF ELSE condition of letter check

```
CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('M', [FILE_NAME]) > 0 THEN 'COUNT'
```

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question - write it with a `Case...When` structure.  If you want further assistance, I would suggest you edit your question to include sample data

Comment: Can you write in pseudo code what you want to do?

Comment: I will have to write a check if any number exists after the letter "M" then do this.

Comment: For the first record (sic) the count is not < 0, it is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (Name VARCHAR(25), [Count] INT);

INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES
('123456M2.txt',        NULL),
('123456M2.txt',        15),
('123456M.txt',         NULL);

SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%M[0-9]%' AND ([Count] IS NULL OR [Count] < 0) THEN --Check for NULL too cause NULL is not < 0
                NULL
           WHEN Name LIKE '%M[0-9]%' AND [Count] > 0 THEN
                1
           WHEN Name LIKE '%M.%' THEN
                555 --Other value from other column
                END AS Results
FROM @TBL;
```

Results:

```
+--------------+-------+---------+
|     Name     | Count | Results |
+--------------+-------+---------+
| 123456M2.txt |       |         |
| 123456M2.txt |    15 |       1 |
| 123456M.txt  |       |     555 |
+--------------+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use multiple conditions for each WHEN in the CASE:

(psuedocode)

```
WHEN {Name contains 'M'} AND {character after 'M' is a number} AND {Count is NULL or < 0} THEN NULL
WHEN {Name contains 'M'} AND {character after 'M' is a number} AND {Count is NULL or < 0} THEN 1
etc...
```

there is no need to try to add `IF..ELSE` logic anywhere in your query.

Comment: I am not sure on how to write the piece - character after 'M' is a number

Comment: Get the CHARINDEX of 'M' and add 1.   The character at that position is the character after 'M'.

Answer (score 2):

I would phrase this as:

```
select . . .,
       (case when name like '%M[0-9]%' and count > 0 then 1
             when name like '%M[0-9]%' then 0
             else "some number from another field"
        end)
```

A `case` expression evaluates the conditions in order, stopping at the first one that evaluates to "true".

Your description is a bit unclear, because `NULL` is not `< 0`.